# An application of congruences: cards shuffle

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Consider a deck of cards. Take the bottom and top cards of the deck and place them on the table to start a new deck.
Then take the remaining bottom and top cards and place them on the newly started pile. Continue this process until all cards are gone from the original pile. For example if the deck has 6 cards (1,2,3,4,5,6 in this order) then we place them as follows: (3,4,2,5,1,6). Cards are read from the top. 
Prove that the cards in a deck of $2^n$ cards will return to their original positions after $n+1$ such shuffles.
This is what I tried: let $k$ be the position of the $k$-th card modulo $n$ (we can start from $1$ for the first card and ignore the last one since it doesn't change its position). I checked that if $k\le n/2$ then after one shuffle the card will be in position $-2k+1$ (mod $n$). On the other hand if $k>n/2$ the the card will be in position $2k$ (mod $n$). Here I'm stuck. Hope you can help me.